# How to store values of array to a variable?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to store values of an array in a variable as i have to display those values in a single button.

My Code:

```
<?php 
            foreach($workshop_details as $class_register)
            {   
                $current_date = gmdate('Y-m-d', time());
                if($class_register['START_DT'] > $current_date && $class_register['ENRL_TOT'] > 0)
                {   
                    $register_btn_text[] = $class_register['CLASS_STAT'] . $class_register['CLASS_SECTION'];
                }
            }

        ?>
```

Now, the values i get in $register_btn_text array should be somehow stored in a variable.

At the moment when i print the array, i get this

```
Array ( [0] => A1 [1] => A2 )
```

which is perfectly fine but what i think is that if we some how convert it into Array(A1, A2) then it will be easy to use implode and get the values.

Need your suggestions !!!

Thanks

Comment: `Array ( [0] => A1 [1] => A2 )` is the same a `Array(A1, A2)`. The first is just a `print_r()` of the array showing the array keys. If you did `implode(", ", $register_btn_text);` it would show `A1, A2` without the keys.

Comment: Is it a tutorial for converting array to a variable? I do not understand.

Answer (score 3):

By default array is numerically indexed.

There is no difference between `array(0=>A1, 1=>A2)` and `array(A1, A2)`
So if you implode  the existing array it will result the same output

Answer (score 0):

Take a hidden element and join all the array elements and assign it.

```
<?php
$register_btn_text = array();
foreach($workshop_details as $class_register) {   
  $current_date = gmdate('Y-m-d', time());
  if($class_register['START_DT'] > $current_date && $class_register['ENRL_TOT'] > 0) {   
    $register_btn_text[] = $class_register['CLASS_STAT'] . $class_register['CLASS_SECTION'];
  }
}
$registerBtnTxt = implode(',', $register_btn_text);
?>
<input type="hidden" name="registerBtnTxt" id="registerBtnTxt" value="<?php echo $registerBtnTxt;?>"/>
```

Option 2:

If you want to maintain key association, use json_encode().

```
$registerBtnTxt = json_encode($register_btn_text);
```